# CMake Error "tf" while building ar_track_alvar

Tags: ros, odroid, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build the AR tag detector package ar_track_alavar on Odroid U3 running ROS hydro on Lubuntu 13.04
Running catkin_make after cloning the package gives me the following error :

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "tf" with any of
the following names:

```
tfConfig.cmake
tf-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "tf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "tf_DIR" to
a directory containing one of the above files.  If "tf" provides a separate
development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
ar_track_alvar/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed

Can someone please explain how to resolve this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193807/cmake-error-%22tf%22-while-building-ar_track_alvar/) by [rookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20074/rookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a standard CMake error message telling you that it can not find `tf`. You need to install the missing dependencies either using `rosdep` or by installing the missing packages manually (in this case `ros-hydro-tf`).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20074/rookie/) on 2014-10-02**:
Thanks.. i installed this package and catkin_make worked ! But I faced a weird problem that it gets stuck at around 22% and my Odroid hangs..probably the CPU usage is shooting up, something that has never happened before..I tried this twice but with the same result :/

**Comment by [spottybadrabbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/25136/spottybadrabbit/) on 2016-08-10**:
*Check out this Odroid image*
http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=16149